# Create an alias to a samba share from the command line

Tags: macos, command-line, osx-snow-leopard, samba, alias

I'm currently wanting to deploy a setup to around 300 Macs. I have all of it scripted and ready to deploy, excepting that I'm having trouble creating a working alias to a samba share from the command line. I tried creating an alias, and then copying it from one Mac to another, but it loses its status as an alias, and instead OSX opens it in TextEdit (the @ in ls -l is also missing). Even if this did work, from a hexdump, it also looks like the alias has machine-specific information that may not work on another Mac.

Say that I wanted to create an alias to 'smb://server/share' on the desktop from the command line, how would I do that?

The machines run Mac OS 10.6.

Thanks.

Comment: "I tried copying it from one Mac to another, but it loses its status as an alias" -- have you made sure tocopy extended attributes as well as OS X metadata (esp. resource forks)? You could try to zip it up and unzip it on the other machine to preserve those

Comment: Yeah, it loses the attributes. If I try to keep the attributes when copying it says something to the effect of `chflags: Unauthorized`.

Comment: I should mention, it says that even if I copy the file as the superuser.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want [mount_smbfs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/mount_smbfs.8.html).

Dropbox may also be worth examining.

Comment: I don't want to mount it, I want to create an alias to it.

Comment: I don't think there is a documented way of doing that from the command-line. The best option I see is to use mount_smbfs combined with a symlink, but I don't know that I fully understand the outcome you want.

Comment: This questions was similar: http://superuser.com/questions/62587/mount-a-samba-share-and-create-symbolic-link

Comment: I don't want to mount and create a symlink, though, that's not suitable, because it would require manual remounting every single time (whereas the alias automounts it when initialised), which would defeat the entire point.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>When you are connected to the Samba share, do you have a folder for it in /Volumes?
You could always Symlink to this folder.</strike>

Why don't you create an applescript or an shell script and put it on your desktop. The script would mount the share if necessary and enter it.

Comment: I tried this, but it does not work in the same way as a network alias. The alias can be used to mount the share *and* subsequently enter it. A symlink does not mount it, it simply complains that the path doesn't exist when it is not mounted.